# Why do I get "undefined reference" errors even when I include the right header files?

Tags: c, pthreads

When I tried to compile this program, it failed:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void *WriteNumbers(void *threadArg)
{
    int start, stop;

    start = atoi((char *)threadArg);
    stop = start + 10;

    while (start < stop)
    {
         printf("%d\n", start++);
         sleep(1);
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        pthread_t thread1, thread2;

        // create the threads and start the printing
        pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, WriteNumbers, (void *)argv[1] );
        pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, WriteNumbers, (void *)argv[2]);

        pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
        pthread_join(thread2, NULL);

        return 0;
}
```

It gave me the following errors:

```
tmp/ccrW21s7.o: In function `main':
pthread.c:(.text+0x83): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
pthread.c:(.text+0xaa): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
pthread.c:(.text+0xbd): undefined reference to `pthread_join'
pthread.c:(.text+0xd0): undefined reference to `pthread_join'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Why does it give me these undefined reference errors even though I had included `pthread.h`, which declares these functions?

Comment: You've got other problems too: you aren't checking the value of `argc` but you are using the values of `argv`. Your `WriteNumbers` method does not return a value.

Comment: @dreamlax: I fixed the 'no return' problem; I didn't notice the argc/argv problem.

Answer (score 25):

You probably forgot to link with the Pthreads library (using `-lpthread` on the command line).

Comment: I've added this to the tag wiki as a FAQ. This question is asked at the start of every fall semester :)

Comment: @cold-blooded why have you not accepted this as teh answer?

Answer (score 21):

Others have mentioned that you haven't linked with the pthread library using the `-lpthread` flag. Modern GCC (not sure how modern, mine is 4.3.3) allows you to use just `-pthread`. From the man page:

> `-pthread`
>              Adds support for multithreading with the pthreads library.  This
>              option sets flags for both the preprocessor and linker.

Comment: Actually, it's "old" gcc which allows that. The -pthread is very old syntax, and provided only for compatibility with older compilers that didn't have -l support...

Comment: @WouterVerhelst I don't think that's true. `-pthread` is still the recommended flag to use, because it also sets any required preprocessor and compilation flags, whereas `-lpthread` only directs the linker to link to libpthread.

Answer (score 4):

You need to link `pthread` library to your binary, like this:

```
cc -o myapp myapp.c -lpthread
```

Answer (score 3):

Do

```
gcc -pthread -o name filename.c (cpp)
```

to compile the program, then

```
./name
```

to run the program.

Answer (score 0):

For folks looking for the csapp solution. Compile "csapp.c" first, then

```
gcc -o filename filename.c csapp.o -lpthread
```